# Set seed for multiple random numbers in postgres

Tags: postgresql, random

The following will generate the same random number:

```sql
SELECT 
setseed(0.5), 
generate_series(1, 3) as id, 
round(random()::decimal, 2) as random_number;
```

Which outputs something along the lines of :

```
 setseed | id | random_number 
---------+----+---------------
         |  1 |          0.25
         |  2 |          0.25
         |  3 |          0.25
```

I would like something such as

```
 setseed | id | random_number 
---------+----+---------------
         |  1 |          0.11
         |  2 |          0.92
         |  3 |          0.38
```

And to be able to regenerate the above every time, as a result of setting a random seed.

Basically: I don't want the numbers in the `random_number` field to be a single random number repeated across all rows, I'd like for each row to be a random number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run it as two statements:

```
select setseed(0.5);
select g.id, 
       round(random()::decimal, 2) as random_number
from generate_series(1, 3) as g(id);
```

Alternatively it seems to work if you use `setseed()` in a scalar sub-query:

```
select (select setseed(0.5)),
       g.id, 
       round(random()::decimal, 2) as random_number
from generate_series(1, 3) as g(id);
```

Comment: ahh, ok. Thanks!